# Could not resolve DbContext after deployment in Asp.Net Core 2.X

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a webapi in asp.net core 2.1 and that is working properly if I press F5 from the Visual Studio, I can hit my controllers, but when I deploy the application to the IIS, it says that it can resolve the DbContext on the Configure method.

My `Configure` looks like this

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration, DocumentDbContext documentContext)
        { …}
```

on my `ConfigureServices` I inject the dbcontext on this way

```
container.AddDbContext<DocumentDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Scope);
```

and as I said is working. In order to deploy the application to an IIS I added the following information on the Program class

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```

The ApplicationPool is running under `No Managed Code`
 do I need to check something else?

Comment: Check your sql server connectionstring for the deployed application.

Comment: it generates the same appsettings.json, I am not seeing anything wrong

Comment: Are you using integrated security for connecting to sql server or user id and password?

Comment: Integrated security

Comment: Ok change it to use user id/password and then try

Comment: same thing not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173915/discussion-between-heinrich-and-mohsin-mehmood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was identified to be the connection string was using integrated security which was not working when deployed to run under IIS as web app was running under application pool identity. Since application pool identity does not have access to database, connection was failing.

Suggested fix was to create a new sql server login, assign that user to application database, update connection string to use the userid and password instead of integrated security.